# Flutter: Get line number for print() statements, Android Studio

Tags: flutter

I am using `flutter` on `android studio(flutter plugin)` and is there anyway i can get the line number of `print` statement or `debugPrint` statements?

currently it prints as :

```
flutter: sarmad@
flutter: sarm
flutter: null
```

It should work for both *IOS* and *android*.

Answer (score 15):

I assume you need this for debugging purposes.

You can put the line number manually in the print statement(putting the class and/or method's name is better for me).

And you could use:

```
print(StackTrace.current);
```

or this (which is nearly the same):

```
debugPrintStack();
```

to print the stack trace which includes the class and method that called the print and the line number, and the rest of the stack trace which makes the output messy. So you can use `debugPrintStack(label: 'sarmad',maxFrames: 2);` to print just the first 2 lines of the current stack trace.

**Edit:**

You can use [logger](https://pub.dev/packages/logger) package which prints beautiful logs with a link to the line where it was called from.
[image: logger output]

Comment: I've been. using debugPrintStack, but then switch to use logger, which is nicer(print more useful stacks for debug and less messy)  and also can control the levels. I compared them in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0nIC37CF_c

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a simple class that gives the current file, line number and column line from the StackTrace.

Heres the code:

```
class CustomTrace {
  final StackTrace _trace;

  String fileName;
  int lineNumber;
  int columnNumber;

  CustomTrace(this._trace) {
    _parseTrace();
  }

  void _parseTrace() {
    /* The trace comes with multiple lines of strings, we just want the first line, which has the information we need */
    var traceString = this._trace.toString().split("\n")[0];

    /* Search through the string and find the index of the file name by looking for the '.dart' regex */
    var indexOfFileName = traceString.indexOf(RegExp(r'[A-Za-z]+.dart'));

    var fileInfo = traceString.substring(indexOfFileName);

    var listOfInfos = fileInfo.split(":");

    /* Splitting fileInfo by the character ":" separates the file name, the line number and the column counter nicely.
      Example: main.dart:5:12
      To get the file name, we split with ":" and get the first index
      To get the line number, we would have to get the second index
      To get the column number, we would have to get the third index
    */

    this.fileName = listOfInfos[0];
    this.lineNumber = int.parse(listOfInfos[1]);
    var columnStr = listOfInfos[2];
    columnStr = columnStr.replaceFirst(")", "");
    this.columnNumber = int.parse(columnStr);
  }
}
```

This class takes in a StackTrace object and reads its string and parse it.

How to use it:

```
void main() {
  CustomTrace programInfo = CustomTrace(StackTrace.current);

  print("Source file: ${programInfo.fileName}, current line of code since the instanciation/creation of the custom trace object: ${programInfo.lineNumber}, even the column(yay!): ${programInfo.columnNumber}");
}
```

The variable *programInfo* now has the line number, column number and even the file name of the current program's execution.

You can print to the console the following:

```
print(StackTrace.current.toString());
```

And you will see how the string looks and be able to understand how i parse the string in order to get the information.

The simple benefit of this is that you dont have to install any library. I made this because i was doing a project just using Dart and i didnt want to add/install any third party library into my simple project. And you will end up with an object having all of the information by just calling the constructor.

**NOTE**: This code by no means is the most optimize code, but it works :D. I would like to see some better implementations

Answer (score 4):

The only way to get the line number that I know for now, is to parse `StackTrace.current`.

There is a package, called *stack_trace*, that offers various parsing methods. You can install it in your app by updating your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  stack_trace: ^1.9.2
```

Then you can get the line number of the current frame like this:

```
int line = new Trace.from(StackTrace.current).terse.frames[0].line;
```

Unfortunately this involves a lot of parsing for getting the current line number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation that should work for code run in the Dart VM:

```dart
/// Returns the current line number of the calling code.
///
/// Returns -1 on failure.
int get lineNumber {
  // Frame #1 is our caller.
  //
  // Example line to parse:
  // #1      someFunction (package:somePackage/someFile.dart:123:45)
  final re = RegExp(r'^#1[ \t]+.+:(?<line>[0-9]+):[0-9]+\)$', multiLine: true);
  final match = re.firstMatch(StackTrace.current.toString());
  return (match == null) ? -1 : int.parse(match.namedGroup('line'));
}
```

Usage:

```dart
print('Reached line $lineNumber');
```

Note that won't work for the web where stack traces can have a different format.

This parsing code is copy-and-pastable and should be good enough for quick and temporary print-style debugging.  For production code, I'd recommend parsing with [`package:stack_trace`](https://pub.dev/packages/stack_trace) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a simple implementation of a print function that will also give you a link to your print line

Implement the function:

```dart
void dPrint(String message, {int level = 1}) {
  var a = StackTrace.current;
  final regexCodeLine = RegExp(r" (\(.*\))$");

  print("$message${regexCodeLine.stringMatch(a.toString().split("\n")[level])}");
}
```

And it will add clickable link on the right.

---

<s>Edit: for some reason`StackTrace.current` outputs differently when using an emulator or web browser and therefore it currently works only when using an emulator strikeout</s>